# React JS Image Uploader | Change Background Image

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image-uploading

I'm trying create a background image updater / uploader component.

An image is set on default however, if the user would like to update the background image I would like to update the state and store the image.

Research so far suggests I need to use the `<input type="file" />` element to enable the upload dialog box.

Is there another way around not using the input element? If the user is to click on the `<button>` element to show the dialog box and then update the background image.

```
export default class ChangeBackground extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            backgroundImage: ''
        }
    }

    handleBackgroundChange() {
        let backgroundImage = backgroundImage
        this.setState({
            backgroundImage: backgroundImage
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="change-bg-wrap">
                <input type="file" accept="image/*" />
                <button>
                    <i className="fa fa-picture-o" style={{fontSize: 20}}></i>
                </button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hide the input element with `display: "none"`, then do some javascript so that when the button is clicked on it will trigger the `<input>`.

```
   triggerInput = () => {
        document.querySelector("input[type='file']").click();
    }
   <input type="file" accept="image/*" />
    <button onClick={this.triggerInput}>
        <i className="fa fa-picture-o" style={{fontSize: 20}}></i>
    </button>
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click

Cache the `querySelector` value in a var as well

Edit: I don't think you can trigger a react event `click()` which is why I used native js. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: This works great, just need to figure how to pass the uploaded image to set the state.

Comment: @Filth try the `onChange` event on the `input` element and bind a function to this callback. Then there must be a way to check if the file progress has uploaded. I don't know off top of my head. https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html

Answer (score 2):

Modified my answer from earlier. I modified some bits to make it work with my project. See code below.

```
class ChangeBackground extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            backgroundImage: 'START'
        }

        this.handleBackgroundChange = this.handleBackgroundChange.bind(this);
    }

    handleBackgroundChange(e) {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        const file = e.target.files[0];

        this.setState({
          backgroundImage: file.name,
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="change-bg-wrap">
                <input onChange={this.handleBackgroundChange} type="file" accept="image/*" />
                file: {this.state.backgroundImage}
                <button>
                    <i className="fa fa-picture-o" style={{fontSize: 20}}></i>
                </button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

I added the last line of the constructor to access the setState. On handleBackgroundChange I added a file reader which you might want to look into later, file can be accessed through e.target. I added a line on the render function just to see if the state changes.

This works in my project, let me know if it doesn't on your and I can modify it.

Comment: Why is a new `FileReader` object instantiated but never used (within your `handleBackgroundChange` method)?

Comment: I probably should have added a comment. In case you later on want to store the image on the backend through file transfer, you could use that. On the code, it only works off of the image stored in the field.